# NEO4j Causal Cluster from Docker not working

Tags: docker, neo4j

1. This code seems to work file from host machine
2. `192.168.1.5` is the IP Address of my host machine
3. When I try to run this file from inside docker, I get this error
   `Transaction failed and will be retried in 1.092425226678844s (Failed to obtain connection towards 'WRITE' server.)`
4. When I change protocol to `bolt` instead of `bolt+routing` it seems to work fine in docker.

Any idea whats wrong?

```
import traceback
from neo4j import GraphDatabase, basic_auth

class ExecuteQuery:
    def __init__(self):
        self._driver = GraphDatabase.driver(f"bolt+routing://192.168.1.5:7687", auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "asdf1234"))

    def close(self):
        self._driver.close()

    @staticmethod
    def _execute_query(tx, query):
        print(f"query: {query}")
        result = tx.run(query)
        return result.data()

    @staticmethod
    def do_read(query):
        instance = ExecuteQuery()
        try:
            with instance._driver.session() as session:
                result = session.read_transaction(ExecuteQuery._execute_query, query)
        finally:
            instance.close()
        return result

    @staticmethod
    def do_write(query):
        instance = ExecuteQuery()
        try:
            with instance._driver.session() as session:
                result = session.write_transaction(ExecuteQuery._execute_query, query)
        except:
            print("-----------")
            traceback.format_exc()
        finally:
            instance.close()
        return result


d = ExecuteQuery.do_write("CREATE (a:Test {name:'Hello World!'})")
print(d)

d = ExecuteQuery.do_read("MATCH (n:Test) RETURN n")
print(d)
```

Comment: All the write transaction when using cluster mode should be submitted to Master/leader whereas read can be handled by any other server.

Comment: `bolt+routing://192.168.1.5:7687` -> You might be connecting to Followers not read_replica which has the routing table

Comment: ok thanks i'll try to change on that basis and see but I thought the doc said u can send request to any and routing will take care of it.

Comment: Yes, with bolt+routing which means the tables built will be utilized to route request to appropriate server. When  underlined protocol is bolt, you must take care of the server